# Pass a variable in mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe containing NA values ​​in each columns. I would like to override these values.
I set up a loop that goes through each column and applies the mutate function.
The column name is in a name variable. As I use it in the mutate function ?

```
df <- data.frame("Colonne1" = c(1, 2, NA, 4, 5, NA), "Colonne2" = c(6, NA, 8, 9, NA, 11), "Colonne3" = c(NA, 13, 14, NA, 16, 17), "Colonne4" = runif(6))
means_ <- colMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)[-c(ncol(df))]
for(name in names(means_)){
  df <- df %>% mutate(!!name = ifelse(is.na(!!name, Colonne4 * means_[name], !!name)))
}
```

## Error

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  df <- df %>%
    mutate(!!name ="
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier to do this with `across()` in `mutate()`- there is no reason to calculate the mean ahead of time:

```r
library(dplyr)
  
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame("Colonne1" = c(1, 2, NA, 4, 5, NA), "Colonne2" = c(6, NA, 8, 9, NA, 11), "Colonne3" = c(NA, 13, 14, NA, 16, 17), "Colonne4" = runif(6))
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(across(Colonne1:Colonne3, 
                ~ifelse(is.na(.x), 
                        Colonne4*mean(.x, na.rm=TRUE), 
                        .x)))
df
#>   Colonne1  Colonne2  Colonne3  Colonne4
#> 1 1.000000  6.000000  1.705551 0.1137034
#> 2 2.000000  5.289545 13.000000 0.6222994
#> 3 1.827824  8.000000 14.000000 0.6092747
#> 4 4.000000  9.000000  9.350692 0.6233794
#> 5 5.000000  7.317781 16.000000 0.8609154
#> 6 1.920932 11.000000 17.000000 0.6403106
```

If you want to know how it would work in the loop, you could do it like below.  The first thing to note is that when using a string as a variable name in `mutate()` you need to change `=` to `:=`.  You can also evaluate the names with `!!sym(name)`, which will treat it like a variable in `mutate()` rather than a string.

```r
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame("Colonne1" = c(1, 2, NA, 4, 5, NA), "Colonne2" = c(6, NA, 8, 9, NA, 11), "Colonne3" = c(NA, 13, 14, NA, 16, 17), "Colonne4" = runif(6))
means_ <- colMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)[-c(ncol(df))]
for(name in names(means_)){
  df <- df %>% mutate({{name}} := ifelse(is.na(!!sym(name)), Colonne4 * means_[!!name], !!sym(name)))
}
df
#>   Colonne1  Colonne2  Colonne3  Colonne4
#> 1 1.000000  6.000000  1.705551 0.1137034
#> 2 2.000000  5.289545 13.000000 0.6222994
#> 3 1.827824  8.000000 14.000000 0.6092747
#> 4 4.000000  9.000000  9.350692 0.6233794
#> 5 5.000000  7.317781 16.000000 0.8609154
#> 6 1.920932 11.000000 17.000000 0.6403106
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Most of the current recommendations for tidyverse suggest using the `.data` pronoun rather than `!!sym()`. So you could rewrite the last mutate as `df <- df %>% mutate("{name}" := ifelse(is.na(.data[[name]]), Colonne4 * means_[name], .data[[name]]))`